# EXECUTE_QUERY on MASTER-DETAIL form queries wrong block

Tags: forms, oracle, oracle10g, designer, form-designer

I'm using Oracle Form Designer with a Master-Detail relationship, I have a WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE trigger which runs `'EXECUTE_QUERY;'` but it is returning records from the Detail block rather than the master block. Can anyone tell me how to return records from the master block?

I have no idea what the block name is. I've tried the data block name and the title above the block and both say they are undefined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Precede the `execute_query` call with a `go_block('MASTER_BLOCK_NAME')` call.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the icon next to your block (in the Object Navigator).

The first field under “General” will be the Name field.  That will let you know the name of your block.